# node js express, how to res.render an image? Or pass an image url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, server

I want have a code that creates a text based on user's given number and i want to different icons/images to this too.

The images are saved in my folder public/images.

I want to not use any client-side javascript, so without document.getElemntyById etc. .
I thought if it's possible to pass an image when i render an page:

```
app.get("..", function(req,res){
res.render("page1",{ image: image}     //(or use image url)
```

and then in my pug:

```
p MY IMAGE: #{image}
```

or

```
img(src="#{imgURL}")
```

I'm pretty sure second one should work but it doesn't load the image...

So my question how can i achieve the way i just described without client-js? And if its not possible how can i achieve this other way?

btw i have two javascripts, one app.js where i get post/get requests (there i also require my second js) and second one to change number into text and image:

transformNumber.js:

```
export.modules = {

numberToText: function(number){
var text;
switch(number)
case 2: text = "example";
return text;},

numberToImage: function(number){
var image;
switch(number)
case 1: image = "example image/imageURL";
return image;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the image as a file

```
app.get('/myimage', function (req, res) {
    return res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

Please check the reference:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

If you want render a template with image, just pass te image URL via backend and catch it in your frontend:

```
app.get('/myimage', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render('page1', {
    image: 'your_image_with_path.png'
  });
});
```

And then:

```
html 
  head 
  body 
      h1 My page with my text
      img=(src=image)
```

Comment: Sorry but i still don't understand how can i use it for my example. It is like res.render, but i want to have this image inside my pug as variable and if i use sendFile i will only have my image?

Comment: @Ovelion, I completed the answer.

Comment: Thanks , didn't know i have to  use src=image, now its working how i wanted it to.